Diagnostic syntax highlight not showing on code lines
I want to set up a custom NeoVim configuration, but I have a problem with syntax highlighting.
I can't find a way to show lint errors with syntax highlighting on this repository. I would like to display underlines for all diagnostics.

In the screenshot above, at line 2 (corresponding to this file), there are two errors:

";" should not be at the end of the line
there should be 2 spaces instead of 4 at the beginning

For debugging, you can find my NeoVim configuration at this repository.
I've already tried to post on Reddit: here.
Can someone help me? I appreciate all available pointers.
Thanks in advance.
For what I already tried, maybe wrongly:

On reddit people ask me to check some things: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/1bivvj9/comment/kxblvlr/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button
I checked Mason, Treesitter configurations and I can't find what's wrong.
I tried https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim.
I uninstalled different plugins to see if there is a conflict and that's not working either.

